# nav list children forcing down parent list on hover

Tags: drop-down-menu, navigation

I've got a dropdown list beneath a parent `<li>`. When hovering over the parent `<li>` the children appear as expected, but the parent `<ul>` also drops down, which is not expected behavior. I can't figure out why. Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/sneakyburt/pen/OJVqqQW) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Welcome. Please post your code _here_. It's required on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you drop down the interior list it stretches the outer list item, which in turn makes the entire top-level menu that height. Your top-level list items then drop to the bottom of that element. You can keep them all at the top with this:

```
ul.navigation li {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

It's worth mentioning that all that behavior could be accomplished with CSS alone. Here's a start:

```
ul.navigation li ul {
  max-height: 0; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
}
ul.navigation li:hover ul {
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/isherwood-the-styleful/pen/gOaaoMo)**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `vertical-align: top;` o the css of the

elements that are dropping down.

Comment: That worked, however now the child list is expanded on page load.